# How to ask for two related datasets?

Tags: discussion

I am a programmer. A friend who lives in the UK would like me to code a heatmap correlating house prices with school results, with the aim of finding a cheap place to live without sacrificing his children's education.

I am afraid that that ought to be two separate questions, but the problem is that I need them to have the same geolocation data. It is not of much use if one dataset is at town/city level while the other is at post code level.

For that reason, I would like to ask a single question, but, (how) could I formulate the question to  ask for 2 related datasets and still be on topic?

---

[Update] with only 5 views, and no comments or answers, I decided to play it safe and ask 2 questions, with the first indicating that the second would be posted, and asking answerers to bear that in mind. See [Seeking UK School performance data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/19880/seeking-uk-school-performance-data) for the first question. I hope that someone can help.